# Imprimir Datos de una Lista En c#

Tags: c#, lista

Tengo este codigo en c# el cual se ingresan datos como son: Nombre,Apellido,Telefono el error es cuando ingreso un dato nuevo y lo gaurdo solo me imprime el dato anterior y no el nuevo dato.

Ejemplo: Ingresa en los texbox:

Nombre:JUAN

Apellido Paterno:MANUEL

APELLIDO MATERNO:GONZALEZ

TELEFONO:12345

Al colocar los datos se guarda y se imprime pero al ingresar un nuevo dato solo me imprime el anterior y no el nuevo

```
     List<string> registro = new List<string>();
    List<List<string>> Matriz = new List<List<string>>();
    string caja = " ";

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioGuardar.Checked == true)
        {
            registro.Add(textBoxNom.Text);
            registro.Add(textBoxApp.Text);
            registro.Add(textBoxApm.Text);
            registro.Add(textBoxtel.Text);
            Matriz.Add(registro);

            MessageBox.Show("Datos Guardados");
        }

        if (radioImprimir.Checked == true)
        {
            int i;

            for (i = 0; i <= Matriz.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                caja += "Nombre: " + Matriz[i][0]+" " + "App: " +      Matriz[i][1]+"  "+ "Apm: " +Matriz[i][2]+" "+ "tel: " + Matriz[i][3];
                MessageBox.Show(caja);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que instancia la lista de registro de forma global, con lo cual todo apunta a mi misma posicion en memoria

```
List<List<string>> Matriz = new List<List<string>>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioGuardar.Checked)
    {
        List<string> registro = new List<string>();
        registro.Add(textBoxNom.Text);
        registro.Add(textBoxApp.Text);
        registro.Add(textBoxApm.Text);
        registro.Add(textBoxtel.Text);
        Matriz.Add(registro);

        MessageBox.Show("Datos Guardados");
    }


    if (radioImprimir.Checked)
    {
        string caja = "";

        foreach (var item in Matriz)
        {
            caja += string.Format( "Nombre: {0} App: {1} Apm: {2} tel: {3}", item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3] );

        }

        MessageBox.Show(caja);
    }
```

Recuerda respectar el ambito de las variables, no se declara todo global

Valida donde defino la lista de `registro`

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda